# Combinators for the Primitive Recursive Functions

Tags: lo.logic, computability

It is well-known that the S and K combinators are Turing Complete. Are there combinators that suffice to yield (only) the primitive recursive functions?

Comment: Is this what you are asking? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48006/is-it-correct-to-state-that-basic-primitive-recursive-functions-are-in-fact-combi

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, but you have to consider typed combinators. That is, you need to give $S$ and $K$
the following type schemas:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
K & : & A \to B \to A \\
S & : & (A \to B \to C) \to (A \to B) \to (A \to C)
\end{array}
$$
where $A, B$, and $C$ are meta-variables which can be instantiated to any concrete type at each use.

Then, you want to add the type $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers to the language of types, and add the following combinators:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
z & : & \mathbb{N} \\ 
succ & : & \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \\ 
iter & : & \mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}
\end{array}
$$

The equality rules for the additions are:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
iter\;i\;f\;z & = & i \\
iter\;i\;f\;(succ\;e) & = & f(e,\;iter\;i\;f\;e)
\end{array}
$$

It's much easier to read the programs you write, if you just write programs in the simply-typed lambda calculus, augmented with the numerals and iteration. The system I've described is a restriction of *Goedel's T*, the language of higher-type arithmetic. In Goedel's T, the typing for iteration is less limited:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
iter & : & A \to (A \to A) \to \mathbb{N} \to A
\end{array}
$$
In T, you can instantiate $iter$ at any type, not just the type of natural numbers. This takes you past primitive recursion, and lets you define things like Ackermann's function.

EDIT: Xoff asked how to encode the predecessor function. It follows via a standard trick of Kleene's. To explain, I'll use lambda-notation for this (which can be eliminated with bracket-abstraction), since that's far more readable. First, assume that we have pairs and the more general type for $\mathit{iter}$. Then, we can define:

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
pred' & = & \lambda k.\;iter \;(z, z) \; (\lambda (n, n').\; (succ\;n, n))\;k\\
pred  & = & \lambda k.\;snd(pred'\;k)
\end{array}
$$

If you just have the nat-type iterator, then you already have the predecessor as $iter\;z\;K$.

Comment: So this is less than Turing-complete by virtue of the restriction to typed combinators? Can the type variables (recursively) denote functions over type variables (e.g. A = D -> E for some types D and E)?

Comment: Yes, they can. The restriction to typed $S$ and $K$ makes this language into a combinatory presentation of the simply-typed lambda calculus, which is known to terminate despite having higher-order functions. You can see how to translate STLC into categorically-inspired combinators in this blog post of mine: http://semantic-domain.blogspot.com/2012/12/total-functional-programming-in-partial.html

Comment: Neel, thanks. Would I be right in thinking that it's possible to represent z, succ and iter in terms of S and K via the Church numeral encoding?

Comment: How do you do the predecessor function with your system (function such that $0\mapsto 0$ and $(succ x)\mapsto x$ ?

Comment: @Xoff: the predecessor function has a well known linear-time definition in terms of `iter`. This could be the object of a question on cs.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @cody, Can't you give me a one line solution in a comment ?? :)

Comment: I didn't want to derail the conversation. It's a bit hard to understand at first read:

Comment: Do we need to manually add pairs (including the pair constructor and the two projection operators) in order for this language to be able to represent the predecessor function (or perform the $\mathbb{N} \simeq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ encoding and decoding)?

Comment: I heard it said that the predecessor was invented on a dentist's chair.