# Enumerating all simply typed lambda terms of a given type

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, lambda-calculus, combinatorics, typed-lambda-calculus

How can I enumerate all [simply typed lambda terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) which have a specified type?

More precisely, suppose we have the simply typed lambda calculus augmented with numerals and iteration, as described in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/combinators-for-the-primitive-recursive-functions/15041#15041). How can I enumerate all lambda terms of type N (natural number)?

For example, the first few lambda terms of type N are

```
zero
succ zero
succ (succ zero), K zero zero
succ (succ (succ zero)), K zero (suc zero), K (suc zero) zero, iter zero suc zero
```

and so on. How can I systematically continue this pattern, while ensuring that only well-typed terms are generated?

Comment: Perhaps you could add a bit more explanation about what exactly are your motivations/which problem are you trying to solve?  There can be infinitely many terms of a given simple type (as in your example): are you trying to get a bound on the number of ($\alpha$-equivalence classes of) terms of a given size, or just trying to list them...or something else?

Comment: @NoamZeilberger I am trying to find the smallest simply typed function that returns a natural number or a sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: So you mean something like an analogue of Kolmogorov complexity relative to simply typed lambda calculus/System T?  That's an interesting question, but I suspect it's going to be very hard to compute even restricted to STLC without iteration, since normalization has non-elementary complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been considered several times in the academic community, from the practical:

Yakushev & Jeuring, [*Enumerating Well-Typed Terms Generically*](http://www.cogsys.wiai.uni-bamberg.de/aaip09/aaip09_submissions/enumerating.pdf)

Fetsher & *al*, [*Making Random Judgments: Automatically Generating
Well-Typed Terms from the Definition of a Type-System*](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~baf111/random-judgments/random-judgments-esop15.pdf)

to the more theoretical

Grygiel & Lescanne, [*Counting and generating lambda terms*](https://hal.inria.fr/ensl-00740034v1/document)

Implementations can pretty easily be found online. I didn't find any that addressed a system with iterators *per se*, but it shouldn't be a stretch from what already exists.

Comment: Is the Fetsher et al algorithm complete? It's a random generator.

Comment: there was another recent paper on this from Paul Tarau: http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03912

Comment: The Fetsher & _al_ paper does not say anything about the completeness of their approach, though a quick overview tends to suggest that every term is generated with probability 1.